# Python - store chinese characters read from excel

Tags: python, cjk, xlrd

I am trying to read in an excel sheet using xlrd, but I'm having some problems storing Chinese characters.

I am not sure why values get translated when I store it in a list:

Code:

```
for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
    Temp.append(sh.row_values(rownum))  

    print Temp
```

**Output:**

> u'\u8bbe\u5168\u96c6\u662f\u5b9e\u6570\u96c6R\uff0c`M=
>   {x|-2&lt;=x&lt;=2}`\uff0c`N{x|x&lt;1}`\uff0c\u5219`bar(M) nn
>   N`\u7b49\u4e8e
>
> \n[A]\uff1a`{x|x&lt;-2}`
>
> [B]\uff1a
>   `{x|-2&lt;1}`
>
> [C]\uff1a`{x|x&lt;1}`
>
> [D]\uff1a`{x|-2&lt;=x&lt;1}`'

However when I print out a single cell value, they are printed out correctly as per excel sheet:

Code:

```
 cell_test = sh.cell(1,3).value
 print cell_test
```

**Output:**

> 设全集是实数集R，`M={x|-2&lt;=x&lt;=2}`，`N={x|x&lt;1}`，则`bar(M) nn N`等于
>
> [A]：`{x|x&lt;-2}`
>
> [B]：`{x|-2&lt;1}`
>
> [C]：`{x|x&lt;1}`
>
> [D]：`{x|-2&lt;=x&lt;1}`

What should I do to get Python to store the above data at its original value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values should be the same. They are just displayed differently.

```
>>> s = u'o\ufb03ce'
>>> print s
oﬃce
>>> print [s]
[u'o\ufb03ce']
>>> print repr(s)
u'o\ufb03ce'
>>> print '\n'.join([s])
oﬃce
```

This example shows that when you print a list individual items are displayed using [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) function, but a string is displayed as is (unicode strings are encoded to bytes first).

Answer (score 2):

First.  You XSL parser seem to return `unicode` values.

Second.  When you do `print some_complex_object` (as you do `print Temp`), Python usually outputs the result of `repr` function on the elements of that object.  And when you do `print repr(some_unicode_string)`, the usual output is something like `u'\u8bbe\u5168\u96c6\u662f'`.

Third.  There is nothing wrong with storing of the values - they are correctly stored, you just have problems with printing.  Try something like:

```
for i in Temp:
    print i
```

Comment: Or switch to Python 3, which prints the actual characters in a `repr` instead of Unicode escape codes.